# Google AdSense Autoads depending on screen width

Tags: adsense, adsense-anchor-ads

I want to enable Google AdSense Autoads only on mobile to shown anchor ads (width<800px), while on large screen I want only a specific ads element and no Autoads.

So I try to add this in head:

```
<script sync src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=ca-pub-xxxxx" crossorigin="anonymous""></script>

    <script>
        if (screen.width<800) {
        (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
            google_ad_client: "ca-pub-xxxx",
            enable_page_level_ads: true,
            overlays: {
                bottom: true,
            }
        });
    }
    </script>
```

And in the body:

```
<style>  
@media (max-width:800px) {
    .ads-right {
        display: none;
    }
}
</style>
<div class="ads-right">    
        <ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:block;" data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxxx" data-ad-slot="yyyyy" data-ad-format="rectangle" data-full-width-responsive="true"></ins>
        <script>
            if (screen.width>800) {
                (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
            }            
        </script>
    </div>
```

The result is that it works, but on small screen (width<800px) I receive this error in console and the anchor ads is on the top, instead of bottom:

```
Uncaught N {message: "adsbygoogle.push() error: Only one 'enable_page_level_ads' allowed per page.", name: 'TagError', pbr: true, stack: "TagError: adsbygoogle.push() error: Only one 'enab…google.js?client=ca-pub-xxxxx:222:259)"}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This should work
Instead of adding parameter to adsbygoogle.js use classic old code.

```
<script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

enable_page_level_ads should be called in scripts once

```
if (screen.width<800) {
        (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
            google_ad_client: "ca-pub-xxxx",
            enable_page_level_ads: true,
            overlays: {
                bottom: true,
            }
        });
    } else {

        (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
            google_ad_client: "ca-pub-xxxx",
            enable_page_level_ads: false,
            overlays: {
                bottom: true,
            }
        });
}
```